# Popup Not Working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the popup link is between the `<script>` tags it does not work.

```
if(data.userdata["money_back"] == 1){
 chat_list += '<a data-popup-open="popup-90">Download</a>';
}
```

I am pushing the 
When it is between the `<body>` tags it works fine

```
<body><a data-popup-open="popup-90">Download</a></body>
```

Does "data-popup-open" not work between `<script>` tags?

Here is a JSFiddle of basically what I'm trying to do:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/tkkpf9dp

Comment: You are using an `a` tag. That is a HTML element, it will only work as markup, not as a script. For it to work in your script, you need to `append` it to the `body` or to another element.

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I'm not trying to run the `a` tag as a script. It is being displayed on the page for the user using javascript. The issue is, that when it is displayed nothing happens when you click it.

Comment: Gotcha. I can't exactly recreate the issue. Would you mind creating a simple fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tkkpf9dp/

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
var popup = '<a data-popup-open="popup-90">Download</a>';
document.body.innerHTML += popup;
```

Comment: var popup = '<a data-popup-open="popup-90" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Download</a>';

document.body.innerHTML += popup;

Comment: That is what I'm doing but it doesn't work. When you display it using `innerHTML` it doesn't work, but if you put it between the `<body` tags it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the event handling. The event that should open open the pop up window may not be triggering. This is because you are creating a dynamic DOM element. The event handling of dynamic elements works in a different way. If you are using jQuery you can need to use something like this

Just add a class 'popup' to the 'a' tag like this

```
 <a class="popup" data-popup-open="popup-90">Download</a>
```

and in JavaScript

```
$('body').on('click','.popup',function() {

  var popup = $(this).data('popup-open');
  console.log(popup); //  For this example you will get the output 'popup-90' in the console
  // You can write the code to open the pop up here 
});
```

Comment: For more details about event handling of dynamic elements please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking the link out. In the meantime here is a  
jsfiddle.net/tkkpf9dp of basically what I'm trying to do. If I add the class into the download link, it throws an error.

Comment: You are already using the 'popup' class for a div. and the display property of  it is set as none. So please give another class for the 'a' tag. Make sure you change that in JS also

Comment: I corrected it and it still does not work. If I take the v`<a data-popup-open="popup-90">Download</a>` link out of the javascript and put it in the HTML it works fine.